Как обходить защиту от selenium?
Сегодня пытался спарсить эту страницу https://stalcraft.wiki/items/other/40lp на python.
Но она оказалась динамической и тогда я нашел URL запрос stalcraft.wiki по которому я получаю нужные мне данные. Чтобы получить  его автоматически использовал этот код:
оригинал кода
import requests
url = "https://stalcraft.wiki/next-api/auction-history?region=ru&id=410p"
res = requests.get(url).json()
print(res)

Но получил это:

Как я понял это защита от парсинга. Тогда я прибегнул к помощи Selenium и решил просто открыть страницу этим кодом:
оригинал кода
from selenium import webdirver
import time
from selenium_stealth import stealth

def init_webdriver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    stealth(driver,
            languages=["en-US","en"],
            vendor = "Google Inc",
            platform = "Win64",
            webgl_vendor = "Intel Inc",
            renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine"
    return drive

driver = init_webdriver()
driver.get("https://stalcraft.wiki/next_api/auction-history?region=ru$id=401p")
time.sleep(10)

Но получил такой же ответ.
Вопрос: как спарсить данные со страницы?

что помешало вам приложить код текстом в вопросе, а не скриншотами?

Я видел так делают другие когда читал посты на этом форуме. Если так нельзя извините.

Referer добавьте в запрос и все, и не нужны будут всякие селениумы... Базовый пример того, как отлавливать и диагностировать запросы, я писал тут.

селенимум 1. заходим на https://stalcraft.wiki/items/other/40lp 2. С помощью селенимум кликаем на "таблица" 3. Парсим как статическую страницу

Что бы сработал простой GET запрос нужно подставить куки и заголовки такие же как в браузере

Нужно сменить User_Agent скорее всего

Судя по всему из всех headers нужен только Referer
import requests

response = requests.get(
    url='https://stalcraft.wiki/next-api/auction-history',
    params={
        'region': 'ru',
        'id': '40lp',
    },
    headers={
        'Referer': 'https://stalcraft.wiki/items/other/40lp'
    }
)

print(response.json())

Ответ сократил
{
    "total": 82492,
    "prices":
    [
        {
            "amount": 1,
            "price": 10500,
            "time": "2024-12-05T10:34:53Z",
            "additional":
            {}
        },

.....
    ]
}

